# Sublime Text 3 behaving differently whether called by terminal or by clicking .desktop file

Tags: command-line, unity, sublime-text

[image: When I click on the icon]

[image: When I run the command "subl" from the terminal]

Notice how when I use the version launched with the .desktop file sublime takes advantage of Unity's top bar. I'd like it to do the same with instances launched by the terminal

Comment: What command do you use in the desktop file and what command do you use in the terminal?

Comment: The .desktop file: /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text

Comment: Subl (which is a bash script): exec /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text "$@"

Comment: Also the .desktop file has %F after the command, but I read it has to do with the system and not the program

Answer (score 0):

If you cat or edit the Sublime Text file you find in the directory `/usr/share/applications` (the name might be `sublime-text-3.desktop`) you'll find the command that opens Sublime Text when you click the menu icon. Try that in terminal Tommaso.

Comment: Already did, basically clicking the icon calls /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text, the command subl is a shell script that calls it too but passes it it's args, but it still happens if I don't pass any.

Comment: Also, I might add that is uses exec to call it, but I tried it without exec but it's the same